# Inheriting constructors php 5.2.6

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a relatively simple question. I am trying to inherit a constructor from a php superclass to authenticate on this controller.

Here is my super class:

```
class Auth_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        if(!session_id()){
            session_start();
        }

        $this->load->view('login_v/logincheck');

    }

}
```

and here is my subclass:

```
class Event_Controller extends Auth_Controller {
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function get_events_by_owner() {

        $this->load->model('Event_model');
        $data['events'] = $this->Event_model->select_by_owner($_SESSION['SignedIn']);

        $this->load->view('event_view', $data);
    }
}
```

This is not working. only a white page is rendered. I'm not sure why it isn't working. If I move the constructor from `Auth_Controller` to `Event_Model` this works.

Thanks!

EDIT:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Auth_Controller' not found in 
../controllers/event_controller.php on line 12
```

Comment: You need to make sure error reporting is turned on.  That's why you're getting a "white page".  Check your logs.  Edit `index.php` and set `define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');`.

Comment: I'm almost sure your problem is somehow related to that `session_start()` call. Can you enable errors by calling `error_reporting(-1)` and `ini_set('display_errors', 1)` ?

Comment: What file is this done in? I am new to codeigniter.

Comment: @RocketHazmat this is set in index.php

Comment: @Lilluda5: In the `index.php` file, after `case 'development':`, try adding `ini_set('display_errors', 1)`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat it worked! I've added the error to the OP.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html  The issue is that CodeIgniter is not autoloading your `Auth_Controller` file.  CodeIgniter only lets you (natively) extend classes by naming them `My_Controller`.  This page has a solution: http://blog.stevenlu.com/2012/09/01/inheriting-a-base-controller-in-codeigniter/

Comment: @RocketHazmat So i've followed that guide and I am still getting an error. I have created `MY_Controller.php`, and moved `Auth_Controller.php` to `application/core`. I then edited my `application/config/config.php` file and appended the code provided in the link. I am still getting the exact same error.

Comment: @RocketHazmat figured it out, my filename was actually `auth_controller.php` instead of `Auth_Controller.php` doh!

Comment: @Lilluda5: You got it working?  Cool!  Glad I could help out :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is not going to work, you should try either:

Move this code:

```
if(!session_id()){
  session_start();
}

$this->load->view('login_v/logincheck');
```

to a cutom library, than run this library within constructor of your controller. Please read [Creating Libraries](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html) for details.

or:

Create MY_Controller class and put auth code (quoted above) into its constructor. Than you'll be able to extend like:

```
class Event_Controller extends MY_Controller {
(...)
```

Please read [Creating Core System Classes](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html) for details.